# How to use Cython typed memoryviews to accept strings from Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, python-c-extension, memoryview

How can I write a Cython function that takes a byte string object (a normal string, a bytearray, or another object that follows the [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html)) as a [typed memoryview](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html)?

According to the [Unicode and Passing Strings](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/strings.html#accepting-strings-from-python-code) Cython tutorial page, the following should work:

```
cpdef object printbuf(unsigned char[:] buf):
    chars = [chr(x) for x in buf]
    print repr(''.join(chars))
```

It does work for bytearrays and other writable buffers:

```
$ python -c 'import test; test.printbuf(bytearray("test\0ing"))'
'test\x00ing'
```

But it doesn't work for normal strings and other read-only buffer objects:

```
$ python -c 'import test; test.printbuf("test\0ing")'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.pyx", line 1, in test.printbuf (test.c:1417)
  File "stringsource", line 614, in View.MemoryView.memoryview_cwrapper (test.c:6795)
  File "stringsource", line 321, in View.MemoryView.memoryview.__cinit__ (test.c:3341)
BufferError: Object is not writable.
```

Looking at the generated C code, Cython is always passing the `PyBUF_WRITABLE` flag to `PyObject_GetBuffer()`, which explains the exception.

I can manually get a view into the buffer object myself, but it's not as convenient:

```
from cpython.buffer cimport \
    PyBUF_SIMPLE, PyBUF_WRITABLE, \
    PyObject_CheckBuffer, PyObject_GetBuffer, PyBuffer_Release

cpdef object printbuf(object buf):
    if not PyObject_CheckBuffer(buf):
        raise TypeError("argument must follow the buffer protocol")
    cdef Py_buffer view
    PyObject_GetBuffer(buf, &view, PyBUF_SIMPLE)
    try:
        chars = [chr((<unsigned char *>view.buf)[i])
                 for i in range(view.len)]
        print repr(''.join(chars))
    finally:
        PyBuffer_Release(&view)
```

```
$ python -c 'import test; test.printbuf(bytearray("test\0ing"))'
'test\x00ing'
$ python -c 'import test; test.printbuf("test\0ing")'
'test\x00ing'
```

Am I doing something wrong, or does Cython not support coercing read-only  buffer objects (such as normal strings) into typed memoryview objects?

Comment: I found your patch [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cython-devel/2015-February/004316.html) even adding `const ` does not help, so this means the suggested documentation is not working.

Comment: `const` now works for me with Cython 0.28.4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue was fixed in Cython 0.28, released 2018-03-13 ([PR #1869](https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/1869)). The [changelog](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/changes.html) says:

> The const modifier can be applied to memoryview declarations to allow read-only buffers as input.

There is also a new [section in the documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#read-only-views).

The example you gave will work in Cython 0.28 if you write your function like this:

```
cpdef object printbuf(const unsigned char[:] buf):
    chars = [chr(x) for x in buf]
    print repr(''.join(chars))
```

Answer (score 21):

Despite the documentation suggesting otherwise, Cython (at least up to version 0.22) does **not** support coercing read-only buffer objects into typed memoryview objects.  Cython always passes the `PyBUF_WRITABLE` flag to
`PyObject_GetBuffer()`, even when it doesn't need write access.  This causes read-only buffer objects to raise an exception.

I [raised this issue on the Cython developer mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cython-devel/2015-February/004316.html), and even included a (very rough) patch.  I never got a reply, so I assume the Cython developers are not interested in fixing this bug.

Comment: I got the same problem too, why they're not interested in fixing this?

Comment: You might try submitting the patch as a GitHub pull request; and adding in some test cases.

Comment: Indeed, have you tried to push the patch through GitHub?

Comment: To repeat what others said, this likely means they did not see or understand the patch, or did not have capacity for its rough state -- _not_ that they are not interested in fixing a bug. It's normal human behavior to reply when there is capacity to do so, even to things you're not interested in.